# adding jquery selector objects into a single jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to combine two jquery selectors into a single Jquery object.

I tried **$("#selector","#selector")**, but its not working and returning blank, do we have any predefined methods to achieve this.

Something like

```
var combined_Jquery_obj =$("#selector") +$("#selector")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Multiple Selector`](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
var combined_Jquery_obj =$("#selector,#selector")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/) method when you want to add elements to an existing jQuery object.

```
var combined_Jquery_obj = $("#selector1").add("#selector2")
```

---

Or use [comma separated multiple selectors](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) when you want to select multiple selectors.

```
var combined_Jquery_obj = $("#selector1,#selector2")
```